# Better way to define a generic type of the implementation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have the following interface:

```
interface Force<T> {
    val direction: Float
    val magnitude: Float
    operator fun plus(other: T): T
}
```

The `T` is the implementation of the `Force`, eg: `class Foo : Force<Foo>`. Obviously, I want that `plus` function operate with the very same type as the implementation. This is how I would do it in Java.

Is there a better way to do the same, without specifying the `Force<T>` as interface? Something like:

```
interface Force {
    val direction: Float
    val magnitude: Float
    operator fun <T: Force> plus(other: T): T
}
```

?

While above declaration works, there is a problem with `plus` implementation. Is there anything better I can do in Kotlin?

Comment: What's wrong with having the generic type parameter `T`?

Comment: Nothing wrong, except `T` can be _anything_. Nothing forces me to have `Force<String>` for example, which is not the intention,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a generic constraint to make things like `Force<String>` impossible:

```
interface Force<T: Force<T>> { ... }
```

This is sometimes called the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

With this constraint, it is still possible to write code that doesn't make much sense:

```
class ForceA: Force<ForceA> { ... }
class ForceB: Force<ForceA> { ... }
// you can now do ForceB + ForceA, but not ForceA + ForceB (???)
```

A true "self type" would enforce what you actually want - that for all types `T` that implement `Force<U>`, `T` is the same as `U`. Unfortunately, Kotlin does not have that, possibly because it has to interoperate with Java code, which also doesn't have self types. Self types therefore can't be enforced, whenever there is Java code.

See also [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371/11).